# jQuery chosen not working for cloned row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Here's my HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Names</th>
            <th>Product Names</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data-wrapper">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control required chosen-select-width name" name="source_language[][0]" aria-required="true">
                    <option value="name1">Name 1</option>
                    <option value="name2">Name 2</option>
                    <option value="name3">Name 3</option>
                    <option value="name4">Name 4</option>
                    <option value="name5">Name 5</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product-names"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn add-new-data"> Add </button>
```

Here I have used the [jQuery chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for the drop down. I am cloning the row. However, after cloning the chosen select is not working. Here is [my code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/tx969q1p/).

How can I make chosen work for the cloned elements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should clone first and apply `chosen` later so the cloned element is "chosen free".

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    var clone = $("table tr.data-wrapper:first").clone(true);
    $('select.name').chosen({width: "100%"});
    $('body').on('click', '.add-new-data', function() {
        var ParentRow = $("table tr.data-wrapper").last();
        clone.clone(true).insertAfter(ParentRow);
        $('tr.data-wrapper:last select').chosen();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tx969q1p/3/)

Comment: Thanks it works for me. The idea is awesome. I used html() instead of clone() with append();